# Como pego o Modo do BitRate de um MP3 em C#?

Tags: c#, .net

O áudio que eu tenho é CBR (Constant bit rate), VBR (Variable bit rate) ou AVR (Average bit rate), eu tentei utilizar o ffmpeg, só que ele faz só a conversão não me retorna a informação do modo do bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seguinte classe implementa um bom Helper para obter várias informações de um cabeçalho de um arquivo em MP3:

```
class MP3Header
{
    // Public variables for storing the information about the MP3
    public int intBitRate;
    public string strFileName;
    public long lngFileSize;
    public int intFrequency;
    public string strMode;
    public int intLength;
    public string strLengthFormatted;

    // Private variables used in the process of reading in the MP3 files
    private ulong bithdr;
    private bool boolVBitRate;
    private int intVFrames;

    public bool ReadMP3Information(string FileName)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        // Set the filename not including the path information
        strFileName = @fs.Name;
        char[] chrSeparators = new char[] { '\\', '/' };
        string[] strSeparator = strFileName.Split(chrSeparators);
        int intUpper = strSeparator.GetUpperBound(0);
        strFileName = strSeparator[intUpper];

        // Replace ' with '' for the SQL INSERT statement
        strFileName = strFileName.Replace("'", "''");

        // Set the file size
        lngFileSize = fs.Length;

        byte[] bytHeader = new byte[4];
        byte[] bytVBitRate = new byte[12];
        int intPos = 0;

        // Keep reading 4 bytes from the header until we know for sure that in
        // fact it's an MP3
        do
        {
            fs.Position = intPos;
            fs.Read(bytHeader, 0, 4);
            intPos++;
            LoadMP3Header(bytHeader);
        }
        while (!IsValidHeader() && (fs.Position != fs.Length));

        // If the current file stream position is equal to the length,
        // that means that we've read the entire file and it's not a valid MP3 file
        if (fs.Position != fs.Length)
        {
            intPos += 3;

            if (getVersionIndex() == 3)    // MPEG Version 1
            {
                if (getModeIndex() == 3)    // Single Channel
                {
                    intPos += 17;
                }
                else
                {
                    intPos += 32;
                }
            }
            else                        // MPEG Version 2.0 or 2.5
            {
                if (getModeIndex() == 3)    // Single Channel
                {
                    intPos += 9;
                }
                else
                {
                    intPos += 17;
                }
            }

            // Check to see if the MP3 has a variable bitrate
            fs.Position = intPos;
            fs.Read(bytVBitRate, 0, 12);
            boolVBitRate = LoadVBRHeader(bytVBitRate);

            // Once the file's read in, then assign the properties of the file to the public variables
            intBitRate = getBitrate();
            intFrequency = getFrequency();
            strMode = getMode();
            intLength = getLengthInSeconds();
            strLengthFormatted = getFormattedLength();
            fs.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void LoadMP3Header(byte[] c)
    {
        // this thing is quite interesting, it works like the following
        // c[0] = 00000011
        // c[1] = 00001100
        // c[2] = 00110000
        // c[3] = 11000000
        // the operator << means that we'll move the bits in that direction
        // 00000011 << 24 = 00000011000000000000000000000000
        // 00001100 << 16 =         000011000000000000000000
        // 00110000 << 24 =                 0011000000000000
        // 11000000       =                         11000000
        //                +_________________________________
        //                  00000011000011000011000011000000
        bithdr = (ulong)(((c[0] & 255) << 24) | ((c[1] & 255) << 16) | ((c[2] & 255) << 8) | ((c[3] & 255)));
    }

    private bool LoadVBRHeader(byte[] inputheader)
    {
        // If it's a variable bitrate MP3, the first 4 bytes will read 'Xing'
        // since they're the ones who added variable bitrate-edness to MP3s
        if (inputheader[0] == 88 && inputheader[1] == 105 &&
            inputheader[2] == 110 && inputheader[3] == 103)
        {
            int flags = (int)(((inputheader[4] & 255) << 24) | ((inputheader[5] & 255) << 16) | ((inputheader[6] & 255) << 8) | ((inputheader[7] & 255)));
            if ((flags & 0x0001) == 1)
            {
                intVFrames = (int)(((inputheader[8] & 255) << 24) | ((inputheader[9] & 255) << 16) | ((inputheader[10] & 255) << 8) | ((inputheader[11] & 255)));
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                intVFrames = -1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool IsValidHeader()
    {
        return (((getFrameSync() & 2047) == 2047) &&
                ((getVersionIndex() & 3) != 1) &&
                ((getLayerIndex() & 3) != 0) &&
                ((getBitrateIndex() & 15) != 0) &&
                ((getBitrateIndex() & 15) != 15) &&
                ((getFrequencyIndex() & 3) != 3) &&
                ((getEmphasisIndex() & 3) != 2));
    }

    private int getFrameSync()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 21) & 2047);
    }

    private int getVersionIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 19) & 3);
    }

    private int getLayerIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 17) & 3);
    }

    private int getProtectionBit()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 16) & 1);
    }

    private int getBitrateIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 12) & 15);
    }

    private int getFrequencyIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 10) & 3);
    }

    private int getPaddingBit()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 9) & 1);
    }

    private int getPrivateBit()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 8) & 1);
    }

    private int getModeIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 6) & 3);
    }

    private int getModeExtIndex()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 4) & 3);
    }

    private int getCoprightBit()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 3) & 1);
    }

    private int getOrginalBit()
    {
        return (int)((bithdr >> 2) & 1);
    }

    private int getEmphasisIndex()
    {
        return (int)(bithdr & 3);
    }

    private double getVersion()
    {
        double[] table = { 2.5, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0 };
        return table[getVersionIndex()];
    }

    private int getLayer()
    {
        return (int)(4 - getLayerIndex());
    }

    private int getBitrate()
    {
        // If the file has a variable bitrate, then we return an integer average bitrate,
        // otherwise, we use a lookup table to return the bitrate
        if (boolVBitRate)
        {
            double medFrameSize = (double)lngFileSize / (double)getNumberOfFrames();
            return (int)((medFrameSize * (double)getFrequency()) / (1000.0 * ((getLayerIndex() == 3) ? 12.0 : 144.0)));
        }
        else
        {
            int[, ,] table =        {
                            { // MPEG 2 & 2.5
                                {0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160,0}, // Layer III
                                {0,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160,0}, // Layer II
                                {0, 32, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,144,160,176,192,224,256,0}  // Layer I
                            },
                            { // MPEG 1
                                {0, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320,0}, // Layer III
                                {0, 32, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96,112,128,160,192,224,256,320,384,0}, // Layer II
                                {0, 32, 64, 96,128,160,192,224,256,288,320,352,384,416,448,0}  // Layer I
                            }
                            };

            return table[getVersionIndex() & 1, getLayerIndex() - 1, getBitrateIndex()];
        }
    }

    private int getFrequency()
    {
        int[,] table =    {   
                        {32000, 16000,  8000}, // MPEG 2.5
                        {    0,     0,     0}, // reserved
                        {22050, 24000, 16000}, // MPEG 2
                        {44100, 48000, 32000}  // MPEG 1
                    };

        return table[getVersionIndex(), getFrequencyIndex()];
    }

    private string getMode()
    {
        switch (getModeIndex())
        {
            default:
                return "Stereo";
            case 1:
                return "Joint Stereo";
            case 2:
                return "Dual Channel";
            case 3:
                return "Single Channel";
        }
    }

    private int getLengthInSeconds()
    {
        // "intKilBitFileSize" made by dividing by 1000 in order to match the "Kilobits/second"
        int intKiloBitFileSize = (int)((8 * lngFileSize) / 1000);
        return (int)(intKiloBitFileSize / getBitrate());
    }

    private string getFormattedLength()
    {
        // Complete number of seconds
        int s = getLengthInSeconds();

        // Seconds to display
        int ss = s % 60;

        // Complete number of minutes
        int m = (s - ss) / 60;

        // Minutes to display
        int mm = m % 60;

        // Complete number of hours
        int h = (m - mm) / 60;

        // Make "hh:mm:ss"
        return h.ToString("D2") + ":" + mm.ToString("D2") + ":" + ss.ToString("D2");
    }

    private int getNumberOfFrames()
    {
        // Again, the number of MPEG frames is dependant on whether it's a variable bitrate MP3 or not
        if (!boolVBitRate)
        {
            double medFrameSize = (double)(((getLayerIndex() == 3) ? 12 : 144) * ((1000.0 * (float)getBitrate()) / (float)getFrequency()));
            return (int)(lngFileSize / medFrameSize);
        }
        else
            return intVFrames;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var caminhoDoArquivo = "C:\MeuMP3.mp3";
var mp3Reader = new MP3Header();
if (mp3Reader.ReadMP3Information(caminhoDoArquivo)) {
    var bitRate = mp3Reader.intBitRate;
    var isVBR = mp3Reader.boolVBitRate;
}
```

Fonte:

http://sahanganepola.blogspot.com.br/2010/07/c-class-to-get-mp3-header-details.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Mendez, aprendi bastante com essa classe. Não imaginava que dava para ler o Header dela só com os bytes. Mas acabei optando pela biblioteca do MediaInfo segue link para download: http://mediaarea.net/pt-BR/MediaInfo

Answer (score 0):

Junto com a instalação do ffmpeg você terá disponível também o comando ffprobe para leitura de metadados de arquivos de vídeo e áudio.

Segue um exemplo desse comando com retorno em JSON

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams video.mp4
```